# Webinspect-fortify security scope

Tags: fortify

Does any one configured Fortify Security scope with HP WebInspect?

I have configured Security scope with Tomcat, but the Webinspect is still not detecting the scurityscope agent.

Any inputs?

Answer (score 1):

For this to work, you need to have minimum WebInspect version 9.1, and SecurityScope 3.2 for Java.